# Export the xcode debug stack-trace on debugger to crash file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If I cause a crash on my app while running my app on the XCode debugger, how can I export what I see on XCode into a `.crash` file so I can open the stack trace of all the threads later?

Comment: I'm also curious if this is possible. Typically I would just have instrumented the Debug configuration to post crashes to a third-party crash reported like App Center or Firebase. So even crashes during development would show up on their web console. Some services let you export crashes, although not sure if it would be a `.crash` file.

Comment: CHeck this post: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/113742